# Change Authorize attribute to return 401 - .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to secure my controllers with an Authorize attribute.
And then simply have a global axios interceptor that reacts to 401s

It seems that the Authorize attribute returns a 302 to /account/login by default. How can I override this?

Code:
Startup.cs / ConfigureServices

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie();
```

Startup.cs / Configure

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

main.ts

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
       // I'll do something here
       return Promise.reject(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: In configure method, app.useauthorization and app.useauthentication have to be interchanged. Authentication comes before Authorization.

Comment: returning 401's is the default, there is something incorrect with your configuration, as mentioned above, the order of your configure method is important

Comment: I've changed the order, but I still get a 302. Thanks

Comment: I started a brand new .net core website with VS 2019 and only added the 3 lines to startup.cs and added [Authorize] to WeatherForecastController. Going to /weatherforecast still redirects /account/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your `services.AddCookie` like below:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
```

Be sure your middleware order like below:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```